thermoelasticity problem with FEM
Hello I want to find distribution of temperature, and stress in cylinder with inner and outer temperature and pressure , I used linear elements with 3 nodes and wrote matlab code, moreover I want to solve that coupled but I have problem in first and last point because those have something like shock. please help me.
My Matlab code

What do you mean by "something like shock"?
